# Displaying javascript value in part of shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is the shortcode that I need to get something working in my site (I'm using toolset from wp-types.com)

```
[wpv-post-body id="3650"]
```

I need to replace 3650 from the value on my url: new-ticket/?parent_lead_id=3788

So I followed this script to make it possible to copy the value from URL

```
<script>
  function getParam( name )
{
 name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
 var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
 var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
 var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
 if( results == null )
  return "";
else
 return results[1];
}

var frank_param = getParam( 'parent_lead_id' );
  document.write(frank_param)
</script>
```

The output is e.g. 3788

The problem is, I can't place this whole chunk of code inside the shortcode as it won't work.

As php is not supported : We cannot just output with . What other methods can I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand... I just made a shortcode that **executes Javascript** and uses **PHP to feed** the JS with a URL query var...

```
/**
 * Usage: [alert]
 */

add_shortcode( 'alert', 'alert_shortcode_so_14229381' );

function alert_shortcode_so_14229381( $atts, $content = null )
{   
    if( !isset( $_GET['msg'] ) )
        return;

    $alert = $_GET['msg'];
    $html = "<script>alert('{$alert}');</script>";
    return $html;
}
```

[image: alert shortcode]